The fields replaced with sed - i in PowerShell contain special characters
I need using the Sed to update some string in the Json files. However, due to the presence of special characters in the field, the replacement has not been successful:
The string which should be replaced is:
"[parameters('test-test_properties_typeProperties')]"

And I want to replace it to {}
My test code like:
sed -i "s/'"[parameters('test-test_properties_typeProperties')]"'/{}/g" $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ARMTemplate/ARMTemplateParametersForFactory.json

or
sed -e "s|"'['parameters'(''test-test_properties_typeProperties'')'']'"|{}|g" $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/ARMTemplate/ARMTemplateForFactory.json

Both not work for me, please help.

Sed can recognise  any character from their decimal, hex or octal value e.g. echo "'[" | sed 'y/\x27\o133/\x22\d125/' to "} See here.

This problem is not about escaping slashes or quotes in sed.

This should work for you:
sed -i "s/\[parameters('test-test_properties_typeProperties')]/{}/g" file.json

Important to note that we need to escape the starting [ here to tell sed program to not to treat it as bracket expression which is otherwise like [aeiou].
